# Does having low reputation have an effect on a tags performance?

Tags: discussion, tags, reputation

I have recently notice that certain tags within Stack Overflow tend to have more individuals with sub 100 point reputations than other categories. For instance, take a look at the [android unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android?sort=unanswered&pagesize=50) questions; At the time of this writing 27 of the 50 questions on the first page are by users with reputations under 100. 20 of those 27 have scores under 50.

This makes me wondering: do certain tags tend to attach users with lower reputations or do we see the lower reputations and tend to avoid certain tags or low reputations users? Ultimately, does this have an affect on the usefulness of the site?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you have it backwards.  Having a large group of users with low reputation doesn't effect a tag's performance, but a trend of poor performance in a tag will effect the average reputation of the members of that group.  People aren't asking a lot of *good* questions in the [android](/questions/tagged/android) tag, and with [a few notable exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/android/topusers) they aren't giving a lot of good answers either.  If some of those low-rep users ask good questions and give good answers, their reputation will rise.  If they keep asking bad questions and not answering the good ones, their reputation will stay low.

Answer (score 3):

## NO

If you're talking about questions, then it would make sense that the unanswered questions tend to have more users with low reputation, since the users with higher reputation would have more chance of knowing what a good question would be, and whether there is an answer.